# Remote recording over the internet

Tags: field-recording, remote, wireless

I've been interested in this idea for a while and am curious if anyone out there has attempted it: Setting up a mic (or array of mics) in one location and being able to record the signal from another location, either by controlling a recorder that is with the mics, or with a local recorder grabbing the feed via Internet, wifi, etc. The application here could be wildlife or nature recording (think thunder, wind, rain), crowd recordings (think a balcony in Egypt), etc.

With bandwidth becoming more available and the amazing automation controls being developed for iPad and the like, this seems like it would work. Obstacles to consider would be power sources, battery life, protection from the elements, etc. But with the many webcams in operation throughout the world, why couldn't a similar technology translate to 24bit 96k audio transmission?

Your thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

check out http://www.sourceelements.com/

i talked to the owner/developer of it about 2 years ago at an AES event, and watched a demonstration. it's a pretty elegant solution for pro tools control and data exchange over IP...kind of like isdn, only you're actually controlling the remote pro tools session with your local system.

you control another pro tools system using yours, it feeds back compressed audio to your unit while you're working/recording to minimize latency. when you're done, you "sync" the two machines, and it downloads the full res. audio to your session; replacing the compressed audio files on your system.

it's pretty cool, we've been thinking about implementing it at work for some of our long distance, co-production projects.

Comment: in a few years of use here, souceconnect has been unreliable at best.  remote sync doesn't lock consistently, and the resolution is often to hard reboot the remote machine when it freezes.  This has occurred across multiple clients and computers.  The idea of sourceconnect is good, but the execution still leaves much to be desired IMO.

Comment: I have been on the recieving end of a sourceconnect transmission two times from a music studio in Macedonia (i live in Denmark), not using the protools recieving plugin, but just the internet browser plugin for listening to the stream.

In this simple fashion it worked really well, enabling me and the director to communicate with the composer and conductor recording the music in Macedonia via Skype, while being able to listen to their audio in good stereo quality.

Afterwards we got all the tracks via ftp and mixed it in 5.1 as it should be...

Answer (score 1):

You could elaborate to include real time audio manipulation for samples throughout the world on different internet site.  Collaborative, live/real time, DAW or Audio Editor style manipulation.  There is something like this but not through the internet, it's this thing called Syzgryd, http://www.syzygryd.com/

Even make a game out of it.  Each person has 30 seconds to manipulate the sample with an effect of some kind or through an online DAW.  With four people and two minutes, think of the creative possibilities.  Russia, USA, South America, Japan.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.silophone.net/

These aren't quite real time (there would presumably be a transmission delay) and are more about worldizing but no reason why its not possible

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/i-am-sitting-in-a-tank

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I heard RIck Wakeman talking about recording over rented Swiss phonelines while playing a church organ with the band playing in the studio. Apparently there was latency but being Yes they managed to work around it... bloody good musicians.

Answer (score 0):

with power, an internet connection and a secure place for a laptop and mics you do this with any remote-desktop software.  Just log into the remote computer and click record into PT, then ftp the files back to yourself.